# How to execute node command in a node app?

Tags: node.js, module, command-line-interface

So basically, I'm trying to make a cli to automate some little task that I'm repeating all the time. And here I want to replace the console.log by something that will run the command instead. I tried with the exec from 'child_process' but it didn't work and i ended with an infinite loader

```
switch (arg) {
    case "React App":
      console.log(`npx create-react-app ${projectName}`);
      console.log(`cd ${projectName}`);
      console.log(`npm start`);
      break;
    case "Next App":
      console.log(`npx create-next-app@latest ${projectName}`);
      console.log(`cd ${projectName}`);
      console.log(`npm dev`);
      break;
```

This is the version with the exec

```
 switch (arg) {
case "React App":
  () => exec(`npx create-react-app ${projectName}`);
  () => exec(`cd ${projectName}`);
  () => exec(`npm start`);
  break;
case "Next App":
  () => exec(`npx create-next-app@latest ${projectName}`);
  () => exec(`cd ${projectName}`);
  () => exec(`npm dev`);
  break;
```

I searched on many forums and also on stack overflow and I think the fact that I'm not an english native speaker has never been that obvious cause damn I didn't find what i wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run it sequentially with [execSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexecsynccommand-options)

```
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

//...
switch (arg) {
    case "React App":
        console.log(`npx create-react-app ${projectName}`);
        execSync(`npx create-react-app ${projectName}`);
        console.log(`cd ${projectName}`);
        execSync(`cd ${projectName}`);
        console.log(`npm start`);
        execSync(`npm start`);
        break;
    case "Next App":
        console.log(`npx create-next-app@latest ${projectName}`);
        execSync(`npx create-next-app@latest ${projectName}`);
        console.log(`cd ${projectName}`);
        execSync(`cd ${projectName}`);
        console.log(`npm dev`);
        execSync(`npm dev`);
        break;
}
```